# Apache Solr redirecting updating to view JSON

Tags: views, search

as title am using Drupal 6, Views 3 (latest dev) and Apache Solr Views. Not having any error messages, but when I add a filter (or any other content) to the view, and click "add" down below, the page redirects to a page of JSON data - any ideas?

Poor research on my part I'm afraid, am not even sure what a useful set of search terms would be. The View *is* being updated, if I use the back button, and Save, it appears that the elements are updating... just an annoying UI issue...

EDIT : Looking at Firebug when I click the button, it produces an error

$(this).ajaxSubmit is not a function
[Break On This Error] dataType: 'json'

Comment: Works fine for me - might just be something on your own particular set-up. Can you reproduce this on a clean / different system? If so, then I suggest you log an issue at http://drupal.org/project/issues/apachesolr_views

Comment: I will do a rebuild and get back to you - thanks for your feedback!